# What is an adapter in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

What is an adapter and what is its functionality in magento core files? Can someone explain the concept?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the below URL to get your answer:

http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-dataflow-default-adapters-part-2

Comment: It would be much better if you could include some helpful parts of that page here. It will help in case the link goes dead in future. Otherwise, your answer will be meaningless with a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

An adapter in Magento is a code that connects different parts of the Magento core code and framework. It is responsible for communication between the core files and external applications, third-party services, and databases.

The adapter is responsible for ensuring that all the necessary information is properly transferred and received. Specifically, it allows for data exchange between the Magento core files and these other components. This is important for ensuring that Magento functions appropriately.